# How to output attribute name in magento?

Tags: magento

I want to echo attribute name, but instead this is outputting array for a dropdown.

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Details</a></li>
     <?php if($this->getChildHtml('additional')): ?><li><a href="#tab2"<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('keyingredients') ?></a></li><?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($_product->getData('keyingredients')): ?>         
    <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('keyingredients') ?><li><a href="#tab5">Key Ingredients</a></li><?php endif; ?>
    <li><a href="#tab5">Product Tags</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab6">Reviews</a></li>
</ul>
```

So what is the correct code to just display attribute name, rather than array?

This is creating an array :

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('keyingredients') ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To output the **value** of each entry in the returned array, use the following:

```
<?php foreach ($_product->getAttributeText('keyingredients') as $keyIngredient): ?>
    <?php echo $keyIngredient; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If you want the **name** of the attribute `keyingredients` (*Key Ingredients* I would imagine) then use:

```
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('keyingredients')->getFrontendLabel(); ?>
```

See [Magento: How to get attribute name and value?](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-get-attribute-name-and-value/) for more examples.